# Is there any way to retrieve an input value from the past

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and it is my only code I know how to use so far. I'm working on a food system for an RPG game. Basically it displays a list of the available food items and ask you to press number to eat . After pressing a number, it prints out what you have decided to eat based on what your number corresponded to. I then need to retrieve what "food" you ate so that I can use it's stats. Here's what I have so far:

```
  public String eatmenu() {
    System.out.print ( "Consumables: ");
    for ( Sustenance consum : consumables ) {
        System.out.print ( "[" + consum + "], " );
    }
    int number = consumables.size();
    int counter = 1;

    while ( counter <= number ){
        System.out.print ("\nPress " + counter + " to consume " + consumables.get(counter-1));
        counter++;
    }
    int choice = reader.nextInt();
    String eatchoice = "You decided to consume " + consumables.get(choice-1);
    return eatchoice;
}
public String eat3(){

    //the food just eaten, 
}
```

Heres the code for the Food Class or "Sustenance":

```
public class Sustenance extends Item {
String n;
int v;
int s;
public Sustenance ( String name, int Nvalue, int size ){
    n= name;
    Nvalue = v;
    size = s;

}
public String toString() {
    String str = "The " + n + "increased your Nutrition level by " + v + ".\nYour backpack is also " +
    s + " pounds lighter.";
    return str;
}
```

}

Any ideas are appreciated as to what to put for the eat3 method. I know I will be using the toString method in order to print out the effects of eating the specific item but how do I refer to the item I just ate? I will take everything as critique. Thank you for your time.

Comment: make your function `eatmenu` to return selected `Sustenance` item, instead string

Comment: Consider using a Bean Class for your requirement

Comment: Care to elaborate on that @Sharp edge

Comment: @user902383, if I did that, wouldnt I get the entire toString everything I call the food item? So I would get this :                  Your backpack is also 0 pounds lighter.], [The CannedSoupincreased your Nutrition level by 0.
Your backpack is also 0 pounds lighter.], [The Crackersincreased your Nutrition level by 0.
Your backpack is also 0 pounds lighter.], [The Cornincreased your Nutrition level by 0.
Your backpack is also 0 pounds lighter.], [The Wolfincreased your Nutrition level by 0.
Your backpack is also 0 pounds lighter.], [The Fruitincreased your Nutrition level by 0...

Comment: yeah sure wait I will answer it

Comment: @JackStudentMHS yes, method `toString` will work. other thing, is make your variables in `Sustenance` class final to ensure they wont be modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaBeans to set the food and then get it. For example:

```
public class FoodBean{

public FoodBean(){}

private String foodName;
// other fields which you wana set or get

public void setFoodName(String foodName){
 this.foodName = foodName;
}

public String getFoodName(){
    return this.foodName;
  }
// override the toString() if you want the object to represent the foodName stored

@Override
public String toString(){
 return this.foodName;
  }
}
```

Ok so now we have a BeanClass..

now you need to create a bean object whenever the user clicks any item

```
FoodBean fb = new FoodBean();
fb.setFoodName("get food name from the mapped list here against its number");
```

now use getFoodName() anywhere in the program, just be careful, the bean object above has local scope if you create it in a method, you need to make a same reference to FoodBean globally and assign the new created object to it, and then use that global reference anywhere in the class.
Further take a look at this simple [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html)